# Convert input of a textbox to the output of another textbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, error-handling, textbox

I'm new to VB, been learning for about three months. I would like to take the input of a textbox, ex. “1234” and turn it into “one, two, three, four” in the second textbox (with commas). No buttons, just two textboxes. This is the code that I've been trying, it doesn't work. I get the error message:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

If I could get a simple explanation that would be great, anything super complex will just blow my mind and make it more difficult for me to learn. You guys/gals are awesome and I'm ready to learn, thanks.

```
Dim boxOne = txtNumber.Text.Split(" "c)
Private Sub TxtNumber_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtNumber.TextChanged
    For Each i As Integer In boxOne
        If txtNumber.Text = "1" Then
            lblMessage.Text = "one"
        End If
        If txtNumber.Text = "2" Then
            lblMessage.Text = "two"
        End If
        If txtNumber.Text = "3" Then
            lblMessage.Text = "three"
        End If
        If txtNumber.Text = "4" Then
            lblMessage.Text = "four"
        End If
        If txtNumber.Text = "5" Then
            lblMessage.Text = "five"
        End If
        If txtNumber.Text = "6" Then
            lblMessage.Text = "six"
        End If
        If txtNumber.Text = "7" Then
            lblMessage.Text = "seven"
        End If
        If txtNumber.Text = "8" Then
            lblMessage.Text = "eight"
        End If
        If txtNumber.Text = "9" Then
            lblMessage.Text = "nine"
        End If
        If txtNumber.Text = "10" Then
            lblMessage.Text = "ten"
        End If
    Next
    lblMessage.Text = boxOne
End Sub
```

Comment: On which line do you get that error? The first line in the example above seems to be completely outside from any class. This is not correct because boxOne could be not yet created when you try to split it. Moreover the code below is illogical. You loop over boxOne char by char and for each char you change the same label with the calculated text so you get only the value from the last char, finally you overwrite everything in the last line.

Comment: What is the business of the `For..Each`?

Comment: that's the problem, I have no idea what I'm doing. The error is on the first line. When I use just the If statements I can get the boxes to work but like you said it overwrites each time. I kinda gathered this was completely wrong but I don't know how to make it right. Should I use an array or something? I'm just shooting in the dark hoping something will work, still have a lot to learn. The for each was to go through each number after the split.

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: `For Each i As Integer In boxOne` There are not Integers in boxOne. boxOne is an array of strings.

Comment: cool :) thank you, Mary!  is it something that fixes your code or just lets it run for the time being?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to create a *mapper*, a collection of items that can map/convert one value to another.
A [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2) comes in handy for this task: given a `Key`, it returns the associated `Value`:

```
Private valueConverter As Dictionary(Of String, String) = New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {
    {"0", "Zero"}, {"1", "One"}, {"2", "Two"}, {"3", "Three"}, {"4", "Four"},
    {"5", "Five"}, {"6", "Six"}, {"7", "Seven"}, {"8", "Eight"}, {"9", "Nine"}}
```

A String is a collection of Chars: to parse it, you just need to loop the collection.
If you need to work with the collection of chars directly, you can use the [String.ToCharArray()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tochararray) method  (e.g., `Dim charCollection = [TextBox].Text.ToCharArray()`).

Check whether the current char represents a number (`Char.IsNumber(char)`) and *map* if it does:

```
Imports System.Text

Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
For Each part As Char In txtNumber.Text
    If Not Char.IsNumber(part) Then Continue For
    sb.Append(valueConverter(part) & ", ")
Next

lblMessage.Text = sb.ToString().TrimEnd({","c, " "c})
```

The [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder) class is often used when we need to cancatenate string. Since strings are immutable, each time you add a string to an existing one, you actually generate a new string each time, which needs to be garbage-collected.
For this reason, using a StringBuilder, the code performs **way** better.

Comment: yes, your code does work!! It took me a minute to figure out how to put it in. Still new to this. It needs Imports Systems.text. I was trying to combine your code with the other code that had already been suggested. I didn't know it was stand alone. thank you Jimi

Comment: If you see that an assembly is missing or the IDE notifies you, click on the class object and press `ALT+ENTER` or click the Quick action (the *Light bulb*). In the Context Menu that opens up, you can choose `Import [Missing Assembly]`. I'll add the Import anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we use **For Each** on **integer** values to get individual ones. Try using **For Each** on **string**.

Here's a code:

```vb
Private Sub TxtNumber_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtNumber.TextChanged
    Dim value As String
    For Each Str As String In TxtNumber.Text
        If Str = "1" Then
            If value.Length = 0 Then
                value = "One"
            Else
                value = value & ",One"
            End If
        ElseIf Str = "2" Then
            If value.Length = 0 Then
                value = "Two"
            Else
                value = value & ",Two"
            End If
        ElseIf Str = "3" Then
            If value.Length = 0 Then
                value = "Three"
            Else
                value = value & ",Three"
            End If
        ElseIf Str = "4" Then
            If value.Length = 0 Then
                value = "Four"
            Else
                value = value & ",Four"
            End If
        ElseIf Str = "5" Then
            If value.Length = 0 Then
                value = "Five"
            Else
                value = value & ",Five"
            End If
        ElseIf Str = "6" Then
            If value.Length = 0 Then
                value = "Six"
            Else
                value = value & ",Six"
            End If
        ElseIf Str = "7" Then
            If value.Length = 0 Then
                value = "Seven"
            Else
                value = value & ",Seven"
            End If
        ElseIf Str = "8" Then
            If value.Length = 0 Then
                value = "Eight"
            Else
                value = value & ",Eight"
            End If
        ElseIf Str = "9" Then
            If value.Length = 0 Then
                value = "Nine"
            Else
                value = value & ",Nine"
            End If
        End If
    Next
    'Your needed value is in variable 'value', use it to set it to another TextBox :)
End Sub
```

And.... its done.

Comment: I needed to add Next at the bottom, I changed the second textbox name to value, got rid of End If and End For at the bottom(it said I didn't need them). All errors are gone but I get a warning that says Variable 'value' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime. Getting so close, any ideas? maybe I copy-pasted it wrong? (still learning copy-paste, haha, just joking)

Comment: @omgitscool Change 'Dim value As String' to 'Dim value As String = ""'.

Comment: no errors or warnings but nothing comes into the second textbox. Tried changing names but nothing works

Comment: @omgitscool Can you snapshot your code and show me your code? Or just paste your new code.

Comment: @omgitscool Nope you dont need to do it. That expression 'If value.Length = 0' checks if the string is empty, them sets its value without a comma, but if it is false, then the comma is inserted. So thats not an issue.

Comment: @omgitscool Have you changed the line ''Your needed value is in variable 'value', use it to set it to another TextBox :)' to ' lblMessage.Text = value'?

Comment: I changed the textbox that was labeled lblMessage to value and still got nothing and I also took out the end for. That's what I was saying when there were no errors just the warning "I needed to add Next at the bottom, I changed the second textbox name to value, got rid of End If and End For at the bottom(it said I didn't need them). All errors are gone but I get a warning that says Variable 'value' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime."

Comment: then you said add "'Dim value As String = ""' and I still got nothing

Answer (score 0):

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Str_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Str.TextChanged
    Dim value As String = ""
    For Each Str As String In Me.Str.Text
        If Str = "1" Then
            If value.Length = 0 Then
                value = "One"
            Else
                value = value & ",One"
            End If
        ElseIf Str = "2" Then
            If value.Length = 0 Then
                value = "Two"
            Else
                value = value & ",Two"
            End If
        ElseIf Str = "3" Then
            If value.Length = 0 Then
                value = "Three"
            Else
                value = value & ",Three"
            End If
        ElseIf Str = "4" Then
            If value.Length = 0 Then
                value = "Four"
            Else
                value = value & ",Four"
            End If
        ElseIf Str = "5" Then
            If value.Length = 0 Then
                value = "Five"
            Else
                value = value & ",Five"
            End If
        ElseIf Str = "6" Then
            If value.Length = 0 Then
                value = "Six"
            Else
                value = value & ",Six"
            End If
        ElseIf Str = "7" Then
            If value.Length = 0 Then
                value = "Seven"
            Else
                value = value & ",Seven"
            End If
        ElseIf Str = "8" Then
            If value.Length = 0 Then
                value = "Eight"
            Else
                value = value & ",Eight"
            End If
        ElseIf Str = "9" Then
            If value.Length = 0 Then
                value = "Nine"
            Else
                value = value & ",Nine"
            End If
        End If
    Next

    'Your needed value is in variable 'value', use it to set it to another TextBox :)
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: I think I see a future problem, the comma before the word will make the first word show ",one" and I'm going to need it to show "one,"  I think there is something that will replace the spaces with a comma correct? Does that have anything to do with trim?

Comment: OMG!! it works!! but why wouldn't you have put " lblMessage.Text = value " in the original post? I was thinking you changed the name of lblmessage to value, but thank you, it does work thankyou thank you

Comment: now I'm going to go through it and try to understand why it works, thanks again